# Connecting to a datastore in GAE when developing in eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine

I don't get something about the use of datastore in a gae app.

I can see after deploying to GAE your app would be using their datastore in the cloud. But when you are still developing the app in eclipse on your local machine, how is it talking to GAE's datastore?

Answer (score 1):

A local simulation of the appengine datastore is created and used - you're not talking to the actual GAE datastore.

Comment: how good is this simulation. it actually persists data? do you lose data when eclipse is shutdown?

Comment: @user1058511 http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore

Answer (score 1):

You can view your local datastore by going to :
http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

while your application is running locally.

(using the correct port for your application)

Comment: I am wondering what if you use a real database like postgres, and go thru JPA, then modify persistence.xml for deploying to GAE.

Comment: @user1058511 The App Engine datastore is not a relational database. You can't simply swap one in and expect it to work the same.